# How to distinguish if merge was manually or automatically?

Tags: clearcase

Is that possible to distinguish if merge was performed manually or automatically?
I'm using ClearCase 7.1.2 on Windows, and I'd like to know if you can find it by watching the version tree or by any given command-line

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by automatically, you mean: is a version created by a deliver/rebase, as opposed to a version created by a manual merge, then the name of the activity associated with that version can help:
If it starts with 'deliver' or 'rebase', it is made by a deliver/rebase UCM operation (which automatically merge all changed files from one Stream to another)

But if by "automatic vs. manual" you mean a version merged manually because there was a conflict between the source and destination version (and ClearCase couldn't automatically merge the two), then no.

The result of a merge is a new version with a "red arrow" between the source and the destination, without any indication as to how that new (merged) version was created.

Comment: Thanks. I mean the second option. What if I see there were no contributors on the target stream after the base contributor? Can't I say in that case that it was done automatically ("copy merge")?

Comment: @user986086 http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm : there should always be a contributor. Unless you evoke a different kind of automatic merge (one where there is nothing to do, since the source and destination are the same). But for a copy-merge, you copy the source on the newly create destination version.