# how to ignore files when finishing private ClearCase branch?

Tags: merge, clearcase

I created a private branch in dynamic view and checked out a Eclipse `.project` file.
I modified the `.project` file along with other java classes.

Now I want to finish the private branch and merge all the java files.

But I don't want to merge the `.project` file.
I can uncheckout the `.project` file to proceed but I am wondering if there is a way to tell Clearcase to ignore the file (like svn and git ignoring files) and continue to finish the private branch.

Please let me how to ignore the `.project` file as described above?

Comment: Was my previous answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23831885/6309 helpful as well?

Comment: I am new to ClearCase from SVN and GIT background. A lot of struggling in the past a few weeks. Your answer definitely helped me a lot. Thanks very much.

Comment: Regarding ClearCase and Git, you can read one of my older answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "ignore" that file by drawing a red arrow (a merge arrow) between the version of that `.project` in your branch to the existing version in the destination branch.
See "[Merge arrow in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397867/6309)"

```
cleartool merge -ndata -to aFile -version /main/a/SourceVersion /main/a/DestVersion
```

Then you can start your merge between the two branches.
The `.project` will be ignored as ClearCase will think it has already been merged.

---

The other alternative is to change its type to "NEVER_MERGE" (as in "[deliver merge automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834884/6309)"), but that would affect `.project` merge ability between *any* branch.